# Get the application name

Tags: sql-server, perfmon, connections

Is it possible -- does a perfmon counter exist -- that would show the name of the end-user application that is connecting to SQL Server?

Comment: [How to Log Activity Using sp_whoisactive](http://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/) will be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no perfmon counter that would you show you this information.  Why don't you just pull this directly from SQL Server (at least as how SQL Server sees it)?

```
select
    session_id,
    program_name
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where is_user_process = 1;
```

If you're looking for data collection, you can periodically run this and store the output of the above query (or a variation of it, maybe with aggregating by `program_name` instead of grabbing `session_id`, depends on really what you're looking for) with a `datetime` stamp for subsequent querying.